# How can I turn on the minimap in VS Code Jupyter notebook cells?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Well, I tried everything from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryrjSsOisis

- minimap enabled: true
- both in workspace and user area.

Version: 1.70.1

[image]

My screen on my personal laptop:
[image]

Same problem on the work server:
[image]

Settings:
[image]
For what reason it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you provide a full screenshot of your window? Also note that if you have `minimap.autohide: true`, you need to mouseover the minimap area to see the minimap.

Answer (score 6):

Minimaps are not supported yet in Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code. [There is an issue ticket tracking this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115266). Give it a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to get notified about discussion and progress. But please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump" / "me too".